# Invoke-WebRequest getting 401 Unauthorized only with PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell

I've the following piece of code.

```
$email = "email@example.com"
$token = "tokentokentoken"
$inputUrl = 'https://example.com/url'
$outfile = 'output.txt'

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $email,$token)))
$header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic  " + $base64AuthInfo}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $header -Uri $url -OutFile $outfile
```

When I run this with PowerShell 5.1, I am getting 401 unauthorized.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

But, it works perfectly fine with PowerShell 7. I don't think I'm using anything that's not available in 5.1; but why is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, and it's quite interesting. I wonder if someone can explain this.
So, in my example above, this line is the culprit.

```
$header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic  " + $base64AuthInfo}
```

There is an extra "space" in "Basic  " - for some reason, this runs fine if I use PowerShell 7 but fails in PowerShell 5.1 (this is expected). After I've removed the extra space, it runs on both version 5.1 and 7+.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because of PowerShell 5.1 sends the header `Expect: 100-continue` as described in [this blog post](https://hochwald.net/invoke-webrequest-and-invoke-restmethod-get-401-unauthorized-without-any-reason/)

try adding the following befure invoking the web request

```
if ([Net.ServicePointManager]::Expect100Continue -ne $false) {
  [Net.ServicePointManager]::Expect100Continue = $false
}
```

you can check what the setting is on each version with the following command:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::Expect100Continue
```